# CRUD in DDD Application Services?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, repository, domain-driven-design

I'm new to DDD, but I'm trying to incorporate DDD concepts into my current project.

For many entities in my domain, clients need to perform all of the standard CRUD operations independent of any particular work flow. I'm finding myself with a number of Application-level services with names like UserService or LocationService that do little more than act as facades to the respective repositories.

Are these application-services as repository facades a "correct" application of the application service pattern?  Or should CRUD-only methods stay out of application services?  If so, should there be a repository facade at the Interface layer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This of course depends on the application and can also be a matter of taste where some opt for a more direct approach and expose the repository directly to clients. One benefit of this approach is simplicity. You're not traversing layers to trace the execution of code. On the other hand, a role of the application service is that of a facade or API for the domain layer.

In other words, application services encapsulates the domain layer and orchestrate the execution of domain logic. By this token, the repository can also be encapsulated by the application service. The benefit in this case can be consistency in that all clients of the domain layer interact with it through application services, whether they are issuing commands or retrieving data.

The best solution depends on your application. If all of the required functionality is CRUD or mostly CRUD, there is no need for an application service, (or full-fledged DDD for that matter) because in this case all the service does is delegate to repositories and therefore adds needless complexity. However, the application service can also be a convenient junction for managing transactions and units of work, which the repository shouldn't have to handle.

An alternative is to delegate this responsibility to the infrastructure of the hosting environment, such as action filters in an ASP.NET MVC application.

---

Comment: in case use case are CRUDy and clients are directly calling repositories, should repositoryImpl be not handling the transaction?

Comment: That works and is a simpler solution if each use case calls only one repository. Then instead of delegating transactions to the infrastructure just have the repository manage them.

Answer (score 4):

Your methods in your application services should have names that represent your use cases. It is often said in DDD that you should avoid CRUD, but in my experience, the product owners/domain experts often talk in terms of 'creating' or 'adding' an entity, and 'updating', 'editing' or 'amending' and entity. If those are the use cases you have been tasked with implementing then they will surely be in you application layer.

If the product owners are talking in terms the reflect CRUD then it should be there, but if they are talking in terms that do not reflect CRUD, then you should avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

If your domain requires CRUD-style use cases, then they are correct.

In my opinion, exposing the repositories directly would be wrong, since the responsibilities of the application services include more than "just" the functional use case; that is transaction control, security, and basic input validation.